# How to pass a string that shaped like an array of some JSON objects to an array via post request

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

There is a textarea in my view that contains a string that shaped just like an array of JSON objects. Like this:

```
{"rowNum":1, "prdId": "5d1bb9ef6f85c704789cacab", "prdCode": "prd1"},
{"rowNum":2, "prdId": "5d1bbe297d9926148cbb2b43", "prdCode": "prd2"}
```

As you can see those are separated by commas, in the server side I want to have something like this to save in my db:

```
[{"rowNum":1, "prdId": "5d1bb9ef6f85c704789cacab", "prdCode": "prd1"},
{"rowNum":2, "prdId": "5d1bbe297d9926148cbb2b43", "prdCode": "prd2"}]
```

Comment: Post how... ajax or default form submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the text add some brackets, parse the JSON and get an array of objects.

This approach requires a [JSON](http://json.org/) compliant substring. You may wrap the parsing in a [`try ... catch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

```js
var result = JSON.parse(`[${document.getElementById('input').value}]`);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<textarea id="input" cols="70", rows="5">{"rowNum":1, "prdId": "5d1bb9ef6f85c704789cacab", "prdCode": "prd1"},
{"rowNum":2, "prdId": "5d1bbe297d9926148cbb2b43", "prdCode": "prd2"}</textarea>
```

Comment: I thought this... then I hated myself... now I just don't know what to think.

Comment: but why . . . ?

Comment: there was an extra comma in my string!

Comment: then just remove the last comma.

Comment: I did and it worked, but the thing is that the text inside textarea generates dynamically and behind the scene! so I got a new issue to deal with! :))

Comment: String manipulation of JSON objects seems like dangerous territory. I'd much rather fix the problem at source (i.e JSON serialize an object that is held in state) rather than use strings to hack together JSON.

Comment: @christopher, that is right, but it looks like that it is a user generated input ...

Comment: I don't know, that wasn't made clear from the question.